# SQL return the highest ranked record against two criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm struggling to write a query that will rank records against two criteria and return the first one that matches.

For example, this is a simplified version of my data:

| Subscription ID | Status | Start date | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cancelled | 01/01/2021 | 12 |
| 2 | On hold | 02/01/2021 | 12 |
| 3 | On hold | 03/01/2021 | 12 |
| 4 | Cancelled | 04/01/2021 | 15 |
| 5 | Active | 05/01/2021 | 15 |
| 6 | On hold | 06/01/2021 | 15 |
| 7 | Cancelled | 07/01/2021 | 15 |

Users can have multiple subscriptions, and I'm trying to return a single subscription for each user as a sort of 'most relevant subscription'. This is defined for each user as follows:

```
IF user has any active subscriptions THEN return the most recent active subscription
ELSE IF user has any on-hold subscriptions THEN return the most recent on-hold subscription
ELSE IF user has any cancelled subscriptions THEN return the most recent cancelled subscription
```

So for the above data I'd like to see

| User | Subscription ID | Status | Start date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 3 | On hold | 03/01/2021 |
| 15 | 5 | Active | 05/01/2021 |

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user
                                order by (status = 'Active') desc,
                                         (status = 'On hold') desc,
                                         (status = 'Cancelled') desc,
                                         start_date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from subscriptions s
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```